# Concatenating nodes from a query into a single line for export to csv in Neo4J using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, concatenation, export-to-csv

I have a neo4J graph that represents a chess tournament.

Say I run this:

`MATCH (c:ChessMatch {m_id: 1"})-[:PLAYED]-(p:Player) RETURN *`

This gives me the results of the two players who played in a chess match.

The graph looks like this:

[image]

And the properties are something like this:

```
|--------------|------------------|
| (ChessMatch) |                  |
| m_id         | 1                |
| date         | 1969-05-02       |
| comments     | epic battle      |
|--------------|------------------|
| (player)     |                  |
| p_id         | 1                |
| name         | Roy Lopez        |
|--------------|------------------|
| (player)     |                  |
| p_id         | 2                |
| name         | Aron Nimzowitsch |
|--------------|------------------|
```

I'd like to export this data to a csv, which would look like this:

```
| m_id | date       | comments    | p_id_A | name_A    | p_id_B | name_B           |
|------|------------|-------------|--------|-----------|--------|------------------|
| 1    | 1969-05-02 | epic battle | 1      | Roy Lopez | 2      | Aron Nimzowitsch |
```

Googling around, surprisingly, I didn't find any solid answers. The best I could think of is so just use `py2neo` and pull down all the data as separate tables and merge in Pandas, but this seems uninspiring. Any ideas on how to do in cypher would be greatly illuminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APOC has a procedure for that :

```
apoc.export.csv.query
```

Check https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_export_import for more details. Note that you'll have to add the following to neo4j.conf :

```
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Where do I run `apoc.export.csv.query` from? From the neo4j-shell? (I have the apoc jar file correctly in the plugins dir.). Do I just use CALL out front of the command? Further...how can I get properties from all 3 nodes into one line for the csv export?

Comment: Yes, that's right. From the browser, the neo4j-shell or the cypher-shell ... all will work :-). Example : CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (u:User)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) RETURN u.name, r.rating, m.title LIMIT 10", "results.csv", {})

Comment: I would accept your answer...if I could just figure out how to RETURN the results in single row....as is stands, right now in your example we'd get 3 different rows; name, rating, and title.

Comment: Well, just a quick try could be :
MATCH (p1:Player)-[:PLAYED]->(c:ChessMatch {m_id: 1"})<-[:PLAYED]-(p2:Player) WHERE p1.p_id <> p2.p_id RETURN p1.p_id, c.m_id, p2.p_id ... add properties as required.

Comment: You may still get two lines (as there are obviously two results that fit that MATCH), but a simple LIMIT 1 (since the two lines would actually be the same but reversed) solves that.